# ValueError : "Embedded null byte" when loading pkl file from S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, scikit-learn, aws-lambda, joblib

I've finished exporting my trained model from sklearn into a .pkl file. Now i want to read the file from my s3 bucket and load it into my API so that the training of the model does not happen online and eat away at billing execution time.

```
def load_model():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    bucket = 'bucket-name'
    key = 'model.pkl'

    file_obj = s3.Bucket(bucket).Object(key).get()['Body']
    model_str = file_obj.read()

    model = joblib.load(model_str)
    return model
```

I get the following error result returned when running the code.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "embedded null byte",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    
load_model()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 27, in load_model\n    
model = joblib.load(model_str)\n",
"  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py\", line 590, in load\n    
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @John Paul Hayes I think I did so by retraining my model and producing a smaller size model that was bundled in my deployment package. However, I did find an alternative but it wasn't used due to execution time constraints.


`with open('/tmp/' + fileName, 'wb') as data: 
    s3.Bucket("bucket-name").download_fileobj(fileName, data) 
with open('/tmp/' + fileName, 'rb') as data: 
    model = joblib.load(data) 
return model`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I ended up doing something very similar. The key difference is that I now check the filesize before hand and if too large, I send to a queue where a worker on an ec2 instance picks it up and does its thing.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing the exact same one...